# Интеграция слайдера с готовой разметкой в wordpress тему

Tags: wordpress

Есть готовый html - шаблон для одностраничного сайта, пытаюсь на основе данного шаблона создать тему. Для создания темы использую базовую тему - "underscores".
Так же есть разметка слайдера (указана ниже). Подскажите оптимальный способ интегрировать данную разметку в создаваемую тему с возможностью управления слайдами из админки.

Заранее благодарен всем за участие. )))

```
<!--========== SLIDER ==========-->
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>
  </div>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/1920x1080/01.jpg" alt="Slider Image">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-centered">
          <div class="margin-b-40">
            <h1 class="carousel-title">Hi-Tech Design</h1>
            <p class="color-white">Lorem ipsum dolor amet consectetur adipiscing dolore magna aliqua <br/> enim minim estudiat veniam siad venumus dolore</p>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="btn-theme btn-theme-sm btn-white-brd text-uppercase">Explore</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/1920x1080/02.jpg" alt="Slider Image">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-centered">
          <div class="margin-b-40">
            <h2 class="carousel-title">Hi-Tech Design</h2>
            <p class="color-white">Lorem ipsum dolor amet consectetur adipiscing dolore magna aliqua <br/> enim minim estudiat veniam siad venumus dolore</p>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="btn-theme btn-theme-sm btn-white-brd text-uppercase">Explore</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--========== SLIDER ==========-->
```

Comment: Ох ух эта underscores... С чего такая популярность? Трудно найти более устаревшую и нелепую тему для WordPress. Возьмите что-то бесплатное из официального репозитория и создайте дочернюю тему https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html. Научитесь работать с современным кодом.

Comment: Чтобы понять, куда вставлять код слайдера, почитайте про иерархию шаблонов WordPress: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: А для создания собственных настроек - почитайте вот этот материал: https://wp-kama.ru/id_3773/api-optsiy-nastroek.html

Comment: Более подробный ответ дать вряд ли получится, слишком расплывчатый у вас вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за советы, обязательно воспользуюсь. Какой фреймворк или базовую тему посоветуеете использовать в дальнейшем?

Comment: да любую официальную бесплатную: ваш-сайт/wp-admin/theme-install.php?browse=featured   можно twentyseventeen - стандартную 2017 года

Comment: Как по мне - лучший способ создать слайдер - это http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick и плагин, поддерживающий повторяющиеся мета-поля изображений - Toolset Types(бесплатный)   ACF Pro(платная версия с великолепным функционалом)